# How to set the progress tint color in UIProgressView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiprogressbar

I would like to know how to set UIProgressView tint color. Sometimes, depending on the color, the default height does not allow to see properly the progress. How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for me the optimal way to do it:

```
[progress setProgressTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xaa0000)];
```

where UIColorFromRGB is:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

(OPTIONAL): Sometimes, depending on the color, the progress is not properly appreciated and is necessary to increase the progress bar height:

```
[progress setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 3.0)];
```

Comment: i have the issue with scaling . even if i add ur transform line before or after changing the color the slider still scales weirdly

Answer (score 45):

You can set tint color of track and progress bar by this;

For track color:

```
progress.trackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Progress bar:

```
progress.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, you can do it like this:

```
progressView.progressTintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5:

```
progressBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 33/255.0, green: 150/255.0, blue: 243/255.0, alpha: 1)
progressBar.tintColor = .blue
```

Comment: Using .tintColor instead of .progressTintColor sidestepped a weird scrolling/cell reuse issue I was having. Thanks.

Comment: .progressTintColor did not work for me .tintColor did

Answer (score -1):

you can just use progressBar name (.) operation and progress property

for example : `progressBar.progress = 0.1` or whatever you want to give a value it should be float
we can change the progress tint colour with the help of this.

try to understand with the help of the [piece of code I shared here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Z5p.png).

Comment: Welcome. 1. The question is asking how to set the color of the progress bar. Your answer does not apply to the question being asked. 2. Do not post pictures of code. Copy and paste code as actual text into the answer. 3. You can delete your answer since it does not apply to the question.